# How to read a specific line from a text file in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, text-files, java.util.scanner

I am creating a quiz game using info from the file. A text file will contain all the questions, answers, and the right answers. The text files will be structured as follows:

```
Question
answer 1
answer 2
answer 3
answer 4
The right answer repeated
```

Using the info read from the file, I'm creating a multiple quiz. I'm saving all the questions in one array, the answers in another array, and the correct answers (repeated) in a different array. Is there any way that using a Scanner, I can go to a certain line in the file?

This is what I have so far. I was able to get all the questions from the files, but I don't know how to read the answers (I'm leaving out the code for the method to get the file name and the method to count the lines because I know those work):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

//for the file, it is assumed that it is structured as follows: question /n, answer 1 /n, answer 2 /n, 
//answer 3 /n, answer 4 /n, correct answer repeated

public class CoreCode {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String fileName = getFile();
    // gets the file and deals with exceptions
    Scanner fileIn = null;
    try {
        fileIn = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error. File not found.");
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //counts number of lines in the program
    int numberOfLines = countLines(fileIn);

    //Every sixth line is a question
    int numberOfQuestions = numberOfLines / 6;
    fileIn.close();

    fileIn = null;
    try {
        fileIn = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error. File not found.");
    }

    //create an array of the questions from the file
    String[] questions = getQuestions(fileIn, numberOfQuestions);
    fileIn.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
        System.out.println(questions[i]);
    }

}

// method to get file name
public static String getFile() {

}

//method to count total lines in file
public static int countLines(Scanner fileIn) {

}

// method to read questions
public static String[] getQuestions(Scanner fileIn, int numberOfQuestions) {
    String[] questions = new String[numberOfQuestions];
    int count = 0;

    //method 2, every sixth line is a question
    while (fileIn.hasNext()){
        String line = fileIn.nextLine();
        if (count == 0 || count % 6 == 0){
            //count is number of total lines, so the index is count  divided by 6 (every sixth lines is 
            //a question
            int index = count / 6;
            questions[index] = line;
        }
        count++;
    }

    return questions;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 LineIterator it = IOUtils.lineIterator(
       new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt")));
 for (int lineNumber = 0; it.hasNext(); lineNumber++) {
    String line = (String) it.next();
    if (lineNumber == expectedLineNumber) {
        return line;
    }
 }
```

This will be slightly more efficient due to the buffer.

Take a look at `Scanner.skip(..)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd read the file with `BufferedReader` as [suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19936488/572834), and save the information in an object which would contain:

```
class Question {
    String question;
    String[] answers;
    String correctAnswer;
}
```

Then after you read the file, you would have all the questions and answers in memory (stored in an `ArrayList`). That way you would read the file only once.